# Can Azure AD which supports SAML 4.0 is able to handshake with SP that supports SAML 2.0

Tags: azure-active-directory, saml-2.0

I am setting up Azure AD as IdP which supports SAML 4.0. Will it be able to communicate/handshake with SP that supports SAML 2.0?

I tried looking on Microsoft Azure website and it say that it supports SAML 2.0. But nowhere defined that will Azure AD IdP SAML 4.0 supports SP with SAML 2.0.

Comment: What is SAML 4.0? Do you have a reference to it?

Answer (score 1):

According to Wikipedia https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language there is no SAML 4 version.
Azure AD supports SAML 2.